# URL Rewrite via .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite a URL using .htaccess

The URL

```
http://localhost/projects/notes/catagories.php?id=2
```

should be

```
http://localhost/projects/notes/catagories/2
```

My .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^((?!catagories\.php)[^/]+)/?$ catagories.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Thanks

Comment: I think this answer is exactly what you are searching for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16389034/4132369

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

change instead af

```
RewriteRule ^((?!catagories\.php)[^/]+)/?$ catagories.php?page=$1 [L]
```

this

```
RewriteRule ^/catagories/([0-9]+)$ /catagories.php?id=$1
```